# While installing jdk

Tags: 12.04, openjdk, jdk

I'm trying to install java using the [WebUpd](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) PPA.

After adding their PPA and updating, I try:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

and it gives me an error

```
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: oracle-java7-installer E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: There must be more error messages. Please post all of them here, now it's incomplete, it's just like saying "I have an error" with no more info.

Comment: this is when i do sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Is that all?. There is usually some more info telling why the post-installation script failed. Anyway, please in the future edit your question instead of adding info in the comments.

Comment: You are probably following some tutorial and you have probably added some PPA (WebUpd8 likely), can you tell us for sure witch one?.

Comment: I did this command
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, and then `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Then do `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` to install it if the `dpkg` command didn't fix it. If you still get the error, do `sudo apt-get autoremove` then `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer`, then repeat the first 4 commands I mentioned.